# how to rename one dataframe in a list

Tags: r

How to rename `b` to `newname` only? I tries `names(lst[2])="newname"` and it doesn't work.

```
lst <- list(a="one", b="two", c=c(1:3))
```

Comment: You need `names(lst)[2] <- "newname"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the `names`, then subset with index and assign

```
names(lst)[2] <- "newname"
```

Though, we can extract the names (`getter`) with

```
names(lst[2])
[1] "b"
```

The assignment (setter -`names<-`) should be on the whole object and not on the subset of the object